# Не могу понять правильно ли у меняполучилось зделать задание

Tags: python, python-3.8

То есть у меня есть два кода: один написал я и одни я нашел в интернете.

Вроде они работают так как и должны, но я все еще в сомнениях.

(Проследите за тем, чтобы сравнение выполнялось без учета регистра символов. Если
имя 'John’ уже используется, в регистрации имени ‘JOHN’ следует отказать.)

Вот задание, которое надо сделать, а вот два кода:

[image: Это мой код][image: Это код из интерента]

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, не фото, а **текст** программы, чтобы возможно было копировать через буфер для тех, которые вам хотят помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая программа:

- Ветви `if` и `else` наоборот: Когда имя уже существует, не привет, а отказ.
- Отсутствует `.lower()` для перевода на *строчные* буквы — так текущего имена, как списка существующих имен.

В обеих программах отсутствует добавление нового юзера (когда он был проверен на несовпадение) в список существующих.